# Make DokuWiki update sambaNTPassword when updating LDAP-password

Tags: ldap, samba

I'm running an LDAP authentication service (OpenLDAP with phpLdapAdmin) on a Debian box, and at the moment it's connected to a local Samba share and an instance of DokuWiki.

Everything is working fine, except that when I'm creating a new user (let's say **testuser**) in the correct user group (which I do with creating a new posixAccount and then adding the objectClass sambaSamAccount to it in phpLdapAdmin) I also need to log in to the server and execute

```
smbpasswd -a testuser
```

and write a password there as well...

Okay, fine, this works, but I really want this to happen automatically, with the same password as I typed for the user in phpLdapAdmin.

From what I can gather, it's the **sambaNTPassword** attribute that controls this, isn't there a way to control this from phpLdapAdmin?? I.e. make the change to the posixAccount password also change the samba password.

And, moreover, since I'm using DokuWiki, I'd like users to be able to be able to change their LDAP password through DokuWiki's password change utility - this works, but it doesn't change the Samba share password, so the user ends up confused with his/her new password working on everything except the samba fileshare, where the old password is still valid.

Thanks!

Comment: is the local samba share in a samba domain member server? Because it does not look like it, you are manually creating local smb users there. It is possible to use samba with openldap and have it work as a NT domain (not AD). If you do, then you can use the smbldap-tools to add the necessary values to the password attributes (https://gna.org/projects/smbldap-tools/)

Answer (score 0):

Overkill: smbk5pwd LDAP overlay allows LDAP to keep in sync NT password at password change.

You can find more details in the

```
 contrib/slapd-modules/smbk5pwd
```

directory in the OpenLDAP source.

More pragmatically, consider [smbldap-tools](http://download.gna.org/smbldap-tools/docs/smbldap-tools/). Then you have then to link the create user, password change commands and so on to the corresponding smbldap commands.